# Adding Custom Columns to Union Table - Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chbGd.jpg)

I'm dealing with the following union between two different tables in an Oracle Database.

the first query refers to vessels that are part of the current fleet of the payer_no. The second query refers to all vessels transacted with at some time.

If an item appears **only** in the first query, I want a custom column that says "current fleet" and if an item **only** appears in the second query, I want a column that says "past fleet."

Output would look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg7jN.jpg)

Comment: What should happen if an item (whatever that means) appears in BOTH members of the `UNION`? (On a separate note - especially if you expect the `UNION` to be disjoint anyway, and the members have no duplicate rows or you don't care if they have duplicate rows - use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` for better performance).

Comment: if an item appears in both, it needs to be tagged to the first query ("current fleet")

Answer (score 2):

Pending clarification of what should happen if an "item" appears in both members of the `UNION`:

The usual way to do what you need is to add a column with hard-coded values and with the same name to both members of the union. It doesn't matter if one or both members is/are the result of a join, or whatever other simple or complicated computation.

```
select col_1, col_2, ... , col_n, 'Current Fleet' as status
from   ( big join or whatever here; do prefix columns with table aliases in a join! )
UNION    --  Or UNION ALL  !
select col_1, col_2, ... , col_n, 'Past Fleet'    as status
from   .........
```